# .net 8 gRPC application on Azure App Service Container not working

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service, grpc

I have a .NET 8 gRPC application that has docker enabled and I am deploying it to Azure App Service Container.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base

USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Api.gRpc/Api.gRpc.csproj", "Api.gRpc/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./Api.gRpc/./Api.gRpc.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api.gRpc"
RUN dotnet build "./Api.gRpc.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./Api.gRpc.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=true

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.gRpc.dll"]
```

The endpoint is `https://************************.azurewebsites.net`. But when I access that url from my client app I get below error. The client is a simple .NET 8 console app.

> Unhandled exception: Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The HTTP/2 server sent invalid data on the connection. HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR' (0x1).
>
> (HttpProtocolError) HttpProtocolException: The HTTP/2 server sent invalid data on the connection. HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR' (0x1). (HttpProtocolError)", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The HTTP/2 server sent invalid data on the connection. HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR' (0x1). (HttpProtocolError)")
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The HTTP/2 server sent invalid data on the connection. HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR' (0x1). (HttpProtocolError)
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpProtocolException: The HTTP/2 server sent invalid data on the connection. HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR' (0x1). (HttpProtocolError)

Everything works fine locally though. It seems like I am missing some sort of configuration in the Azure App service but not able to figure out. Appreciate your help. Thank you!

Ramesh

I tried setting "HTTP 2.0 Proxy" to both On and gRpc Only but no use